# libwebp apparently successfully installed but "cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000018986F14B80>"

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, webp

I have spent almost 20 hours researching this and have gotten nowhere so I would **REALLY** appreciate anyone and everyone's assistance.

I'm downloading webp images to convert to JPG. This is my code, which others in the comments below tested and works:

```
webp_format = requests.get("https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_NQ_NP_711864-MLB46594538199_072021-O.webp")

buffer = BytesIO(webp_format.content)

image = Image.open(buffer)

image.convert('RGB')

image.save(buffer, 'jpeg')

image.save('C:\\Users\\Ze\\Documents\\Dropshipping\\Scraping\\Competitor product lists\\Selected\\test.jpg')

buffer.seek(0)
buffer.truncate()

file = {'file' : ('name', buffer, 'image/jpg')}

return file
```

The problematic step is Image.open, I think. It says:

**"UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000018986F44040>"**

The weird thing is print **(features.check_module('webp'))** says **False** but **python -m PIL** says "WEBP support ok, loaded 1.2.0", "WEBP Transparency support ok", "WEBP Animation support ok" and everywhere else where it said WEBP as well". Also, there used to be a little message along with the above error that webp support was not installed but it's gone now after I reinstalled both libwebp and PIL and check_module still says False.

What could be causing this problem and, much more importantly, how can I solve it?

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying! Here you go https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_NQ_NP_711864-MLB46594538199_072021-O.webp

Comment: Me too, but that's the point. I have hundreds of thousands of WebP images. Libwebp should make it work for webp images also but it's not working

Comment: _Me too_ What do you mean?  You said it didn't work.  Your code works fine for me.  Does it work for you?

Comment: For JPGs I mean. It works for JPGs, PNGs, etc. but I need WebP

Comment: Oh I misread what Python_user said, please excuse me. I understood "If I get a JPG", my apologies. Yes, so the problem is with PIL + libwebp. I tried reinstalling everything multiple times.

Comment: what is the Pillow version you have there? on mac command would be `pip freeze | grep Pillow` and windows `pip freeze | findstr Pillow`  i tried on Pillow==8.3.1 and works well.  if you have some old version try to upgrade it `pip install --upgrade Pillow`

Comment: Unfortunately mine is up-to-date. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I have seen trouble with some packages based on os. I am on mac - Catalina. I created a virtual environment and installed requests and Pillow. so `pip freeze` gave me-->  certifi==2021.5.30
charset-normalizer==2.0.4
idna==3.2
Pillow==8.3.1
requests==2.26.0
urllib3==1.26.6 . Then when I ran the script it created test.jpg. you can try this so its easy to understand that script is getting executed in same setup.

Comment: Thank you very much! I actually decided to just go ahead and reinstall Windows. It was long overdue anyway and I have literally spent over 20 hours on this. Thank you very much for all your help either way!

Comment: I want to try one last thing. I went step by step following Image.open to see what happened and I saw the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL._webp'". It should be installed, though, since python -m PIL clearly says so. Do you guys have any other ideas?

Comment: refer this post if you are on anaconda - [webp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55349110/webp-support-not-installed-error-with-pillow-included-in-anaconda). this code need to return True `print (features.check_module('webp'))` . Then only you are sure that all is installed well.